# Metal Shader Debugging - Capture GPU Frame

Tags: ios, debugging, metal

I want to debug my metal shader, tho the "Capture GPU Frame" button is not visible and unavailable in the debug menu.

My scheme was initially set up like this:

- Capture GPU Frame: *Automatically Enabled*
- Metal API Validation: *Enabled*

Tho when I change the Capture GPU Frame option to *Metal*, I do see the capture button, tho my app crashes when I'm trying to make the render command encoder:

```
commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: ...)
```

> validateRenderPassDescriptor:644: failed assertion `Texture at colorAttachment[0] has usage (0x01) which doesn't specify MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget (0x04)'

Question one: Why do I need to specify the usage? (It works in *Automatically Enabled* mode)

Question two: How do I specify the `MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget`?

Running betas; Xcode 10 and iOS 12.

Comment: Are you just drawing a single pass into the drawable of an `MTKView`? If so, try setting the view’s `framebufferOnly` property to `false`. This should happen automatically when capture is enabled, but it sounds like you may be hitting a bug.

Comment: Short awnser, yes, tho I’ve set up a flow that allows background rendering too. Thanks, I’ll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With newer versions of Xcode you need to explicitly set MTLTextureDescriptor.usage, for my case (a render target) that looks like this:

```
textureDescriptor.usage = MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget|MTLTextureUsageShaderRead;
```

The above setting indicates that a texture can be used as a render target and that it could also be read after that by another shader. As the comment above mentioned, you may also want to set the framebufferOnly property, here is how I do that:

```
if (isCaptureRenderedTextureEnabled) {
  mtkView.framebufferOnly = false;
}
```

Note that this framebufferOnly only setting is left as the default of true when for the optimized case (isCaptureRenderedTextureEnabled = false) which makes it easy to inspect the data that will be rendered in the view (the output of the shader).

Comment: Cool, didn’t realize I could use the or-operator, sweet. I’ll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specify usage purpose

```
textureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget , .shaderRead]
```

or

```
textureDescriptor.usage = MTLTextureUsage(rawValue: MTLTextureUsage.renderTarget.rawValue | MTLTextureUsage.shaderRead.rawValue)
```